# How to terminate a program from a child process?

Tags: c, process, fork, exit, terminate

I am trying to terminate my program which takes a line that is full of commands from a file and then process each command using  `execvp`

However,Whenever I encounter `quit`, I want to immediately exit processing the commands and ignore all other commands that are coming after it.

I tried to do this the following way using `exit()`

```
for(int i =0;i < numOfCommands;i++)
{
    childPid = fork();
    if(childPid == 0)
    {
        if(execvp(commands[i].cmd[0],commands[i].cmd) == -1)
         {
            /*if(strcmp(commands[i].cmd[0],"quit"))
            {
                done = true;
                return;
            }*/

            if(strcmp(commands[i].cmd[0],"quit")==0)
            {
                printf("Quit command found ! \n Quitting .");
                done = true;
                //return;
                 exit(0);


            }
            printf("Command %s is unknown \n", commands[i].cmd[0]);

        }
    }
    else 
    {
                    //parent process
        wait(&child_status);
    }
  }
}
```

And this happens inside of the child process, after forking of course. But the problem is that my program keeps processing the remaining commands that comes after quit before exiting the program !

Comment: Use a debugger. `_exit()` does not return which means you are doing something else wrong.

Comment: Please show a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).  Sounds like you may need to stop processing and/or exit the parent process not the child. But It is impossible to tell for sure from this incomplete code snippet.

Comment: @kaylum  edited my code to show the context

Comment: As guessed you are exiting the child not the parent and it is the parent process that kicks off each command. If you want to stop processing then the parent process should check the command for "quit" before calling `fork`.

Comment: @kaylum thank you so much Kaylum, i got it to work, but can you explain why it doesn't work when I have it in the child?

Comment: Very simple. Exiting the child process does not in any way mean that the parent process will also automatically exit. They run independently (unless there is explicit IPC). Since the parent process is the one running the `for` loop it will continue to do so regardless of whether the child process exits or not.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `kill(2)` to send a signal to the process group.  You can do this in the parent or any of the children.

`int kill(pid_t pid, int sig);`

> If pid equals 0, then sig is sent to every process in the process group of the calling process.

For example:

```
kill(0, SIGTERM);
```

Answer (score 1):

I think a better way to deal with this is to check for the `quit` command in the parent process **before** forking the child.

But if you want to do it in the child, you can send a signal to the parent.

```
kill(getppid(), SIGUSR1);
```

The parent process will need to establish a signal handler for `SIGUSR1` that cleans everything up and exits. Or you could send a signal like `SIGINT`, whose default action is to kill the process, but it's better to implement a clean exit.

Also, in your code, you should check for the `quit` command **before** calling `execvp`. Otherwise, if there's a `quit` program in the user's path, it will never match your built-in `quit`, since `execvp` will succeed and not return.

Comment: Can you please explain why I need to handle quit in the parent and not the child, I always thought about the parent just waiting for the child to finish kinda of thing

Comment: You only need to fork a child if it's going to run a program. If the purpose of the command is to control the shell, the shell should process it directly.